# java multithreading method that can acess atmost 3 threads concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Hi today in interview they asked a multi threading question that create a procedure in which there is a method getDBConnect() so that atmost 3 threads can access it concurrently. if 4th thraed try to access getDBConnect() method then 4th thread will go on wait state if anyone of 3 thread release the method getDBConnect() then 4th thread will access the getDBConnect() method using simple thread or executor thread.

Please help me to understand how can i make program of multi threading so that above criteria should be satisfied.

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request satisfiable by simply looking through the javadocs for the Java SE built-in classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write code for you. But I can hint what this question is about. There is very interesting primitive of multithreading synchronization called Semaphore. JDK contains detailed description and sample of use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: thanks @Dewfy It will help lot. I am trying to make that code with this help.then I will check this with answer. please give me some time then i will mark as an answer.